# PDF format is not getting downloaded using blob

Tags: javascript

Here is the Javascript code

```
function DownloadFromUrl(url, mime) {
  axios({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob', // important
  }).then((response) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.' + mime);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  });
}

$("#dl_file").click(() => {
    DownloadFromUrl("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf", "pdf");
});
```

Here is HTML code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js">
<button id="dl_file">
  Download File
</button>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/maayuresh/uzfsgjet/2/

Answer (score 0):

So I did this not too long ago, also with Axios but had some slightly different settings.

The main thing is that the `responseType` sent in the request was set to `'arraybuffer'` and when processing the response I provided the `mimeType` when creating the Blob `new Blob([result.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });`.